# Read string from DigiUSB

Tags: c++, arduino-ide, usb, attiny, digispark

I wrote simple code for my Digispark (Attiny85 with Micronucleus bootloader) in Arduino IDE:

```
#include <DigiUSB.h>

String inst;

void setup() {
  DigiUSB.begin();
  pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (DigiUSB.available()) {

    char inp = DigiUSB.read();

    if (inp == '\n') { 
      DigiUSB.println(inst);
      DigiUSB.println(inst.length());
      inst = "";

    } 
    else {
      inst += inp;
      }
  }

  DigiUSB.delay(1);
}
```

DigiUSB works just like Serial communication in classic boards

If i send string and newline char i expect it to output this string back and print its length, but instead i receiving null string and 0 in any case

Is it problem with code or microcontroller itself?

[image: DigiUSB monitor software]

---

**EDIT:**
Its seems to be digispark library problem itself:

DigiUSB.println() and DigiUSB.print() accept only char arrays

Also, there is no toCharArray() from classic arduino lib and no c_str() so i cant use atoi()

Comment: At DigiBlink example DigiUSB.refresh(); calls first at "loop()".
Maybe it could solve issue. https://github.com/digistump/DigisparkArduinoIntegration/blob/master/libraries/DigisparkUSB/examples/DigiBlink/DigiBlink.ino